# How to increase scroll speed in tmux?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I am using tmux 1.8 along with item2 3.0.4. My scroll speed using mouse is too slow, how can I increase the speed of the scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps setting "Double-report scroll wheel events to work around tmux scrolling bug" to true will fix it under:  Preferences > Advanced > Search: "scroll".

If it's not there try the Nightly. (on 3.0.20161030-nightly)